# JS Смена текста в кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста как сменить текст в кнопке при клике на неё и с последующим возвратом текста после второго нажатия.

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, т.к. в JS я пока не разбирался.

P.S. На сайте используется фреймворк Bootstrap 4.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" id="show"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли! Занесу в сниппеты и возьмусь за изучение JS как можно скорее :)

Answer (score 4):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn > span');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  btn.innerHTML =
    (btn.innerHTML === 'Показать всё') ? btn.innerHTML = 'Скрыть всё' : btn.innerHTML = 'Показать всё';
})
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" id="show"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
```

И второй вариант, если кнопка не первая или не единственная....

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn > span');
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {

  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.innerHTML =
      (this.innerHTML === 'Показать всё') ? this.innerHTML = 'Скрыть всё' : this.innerHTML = 'Показать всё';
  })

}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" id="show"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" id="show_2"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" id="show_3"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" id="show_4"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
```

Comment: Что если элемент **.btn > span**  не первый на странице?

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, задать класс тегу span и указать класс (в моём понимании)

Comment: @dragunov_m у элемента есть id =)

Comment: @Mr.Brightside не заметил :)

Comment: @Air Вот тоже заметил что в первом варианте кнопка меняется правильно, но потом начинаются приколы.
Заключаются они в том что кнопка оставляет название, но спойлер работает.

Comment: @dragunov_m, привет, ты лучше новый вопрос задай и покажи проблему наглядно... я так понимаю это у тебя аккордеон?

Comment: @Air, добрый вечер :)
Да, это аккордеон.
Наглядный пример можно посмотреть на сайте test.expertpc.by, в разделе услуг кнопка "Показать всё"

Comment: Ну проблема есть, увидел...  Ну тебе одной ссылкой тут ни кто не поможет, советую задать новый вопрос, выложить сюда пример и описать проблему....

Answer (score 3):

Ответы конечно уже даны, но пришло в голову забавное решение с jQuery :)))

```js
$('button').click(function()
{
  $('span').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  <span>Показать всё</span>
  <span style="display:none">Вернуть назад</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Подробней о [`text`.](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    return text === "Показать всё" ? "Скрыть всё" : "Показать всё";
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" id="show"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
```

Comment: Проблема в том что кнопка меняет название по первому клику, по второму она открывает спойлер и сохраняет изменённое название. По третьему клику оно меняет на исходное, но в результате мы имеем не то что нужно.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку, она может открыть аккордеон и не изменить название.
Наглядный пример: test.expertpc.by